# zyBooks 5.19. Lab exact change function with multiple returns

Tags: python, function

In my Intro to Python class, I have the following problem

Write a program with total change amount as an integer input that outputs the change using the fewest coins, one coin type per line. The coin types are dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 penny vs. 2 pennies.

Ex: If the input is:

0
or less, the output is:

no change
Ex: If the input is:

45
the output is:

1 quarter
2 dimes
Your program must define and call the following function. The function exact_change() should return num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, and num_pennies.
def exact_change(user_total)

I have the code written and it works beautifully until I submit it for grading. Three out of five tests are successful, on the last two tests I get a message saying that the program returned no output. the difference between the last two tests is that they step over the input and hardcode a value into the function. When I hardcode the same value into the function I get the expected result. I have run the code in PyCharm with no issues and ran it through the debugger and it doesn't find any errors.

I have emailed my professor and her response with that there seems to be no issue with my code, but that zyBooks is very particular about things.

Below is my code to review. Any thoughts and suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
# Define exact change function and use the modulus function to set each coin varible
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_dollars = user_total // 100
    user_total %= 100

    num_quarters = user_total // 25
    user_total %= 25

    num_dimes = user_total // 10
    user_total %= 10

    num_nickels = user_total // 5
    user_total %= 5

    num_pennies = user_total
    return num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies


# Define print parameters
def print_change(coins, coin_name):
    if coins == 1:
        print(f"1 {coin_name}")
    elif coins > 1:
        print(f"{coins} {coin_name}s")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    input_val = int(input())    
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)


if num_dollars + num_quarters + num_dimes + num_nickels + num_pennies <= 0:
    print('no change')
else:  # else call print function to print exact change in the smallest amout of coins.
    print_change(num_dollars, 'dollar')
    print_change(num_quarters, 'quarter')
    print_change(num_dimes, 'dime')
    print_change(num_nickels, 'nickel')
 if num_pennies == 1:
    print('1 penny')
elif num_pennies > 1:
    print(num_pennies, 'pennies')
```

My sister is a senior level software engineer with 20+ years of experience and she can find nothing wrong with the code. So what is zyBooks looking for that we are all missing

EDIT: Here is the report I get back from zyBook

1:Compare output                     1 / 1
Input          45
Your output  1 quarter
2 dimes

2:Compare output                     1 / 1
Input         0
Your output   no change

3:Compare output                     2 / 2
Input        156
Your output  1 dollar
2 quarters
1 nickel
1 penny
4:Unit test                           0 / 3
exact_change(300)
Your test produced no output.

5:Unit test                           0 / 3
exact_change(141)
Your test produced no output.

As you can see on test for and five they hardcoded the function value in instead of using the input_val

Comment: What do you mean by "they step over the input"?

Comment: You code seems good, but: 
What is the expected output format of the function ? do you considered zyBooks maybe expects the function returns the string ? or a list, or a tuple .. i do not know

Comment: Add the output report and more info on stepping over input. but to clarify, instead of using exact_change(input_val)  they are using exact_change(300)  which returns no output

Comment: Problem solved  there was an indentation error the print function call wasn't in the name== main loop.